# Thread in java is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, eclipse-luna

previous the same thread was running in java eclipse luna, but interruptions appeared I changed to Java EE IDE, the same thread which previous ran in luna now is not running in Java EE IDE, here it is

```
public void clockTime(){
        Thread clock=new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    for(;;){
                        Calendar cald=new GregorianCalendar();
                         day=cald.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                         month=cald.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        year=cald.get(Calendar.YEAR);


                         seconds=cald.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                         minutes=cald.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                         hours=cald.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                         lblClock.setText("<html>"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+"<br>"+day+"/"+month+"/"+year+"</html>");
                    sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        clock.start();

        }
```

please may any one help me??.
calling the method to constructor I have already done not seen here, but if I remove the thread the method is executed since it displays the time and date as required but not changing due to absence of loop and forever loop.

Comment: your question is not clear, you should edit it to improve its style and ease its understanding.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a Swing application then:

- Make sure that you start the application on the Swing event thread, by calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);` where your GUI is started up in that Runnable
- You're making a key Swing call **off** of the Swing event thread (EDT) in the code above, namely the `lblClock.setText(...)` call. This also should be called only on the Swing event thread, in the same way as point above.
- Or you could use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and then make the setText call in the publish / process method pair.
- Or (and this is what I would do), chuck all that code above and use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). It's much simpler, and you wouldn't have to worry about on/off Swing event since all calls would be on the event thread.

If you go the Swing Timer route, you'd construct pass in its constructor an int equal to the desired delay, here 1000 msecs. The Timer's ActionListener is called repeatedly, and in that you'd get your time values, and then use it to create a String that you pass to your JLabel.

For example, something roughly like:

```
int timerDelay = 1000;
Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // calculations to get time Strings
        String text = ..... // use calculations above
        lblClock.setText(text);
    }   
});
timer.start();
```

Note that code has not been tested